# Why is my boolean modifier not subtracting text properly from the wall of the column?

Tags: bezier-curves, text-object, curve-modifier, boolean-modifier

I am trying to create a hollow column with words cut out of the side using Blender. I have been following certain steps to achieve this, but I am not getting the desired results. The first time I attempted this, after applying the boolean modifier, large chunks of the column disappeared in the shape of stretched-out triangles. However, in subsequent attempts, the boolean modifier did not seem to have any effect unless I selected 'intersect.' In my most recent attempt, the boolean modifier made everything disappear except for the text, regardless of the operation selected.

I am not sure what I have changed unintentionally between each attempt, but none of the outcomes has been what I am looking for.

*I have reattempted this using extrude. Unfortunately, this only provided the same results as earlier, where nothing would happen when doing the boolean modifier unless selecting inverse. When selecting inverse, the column disappears and only the text remains. Added a photo of what I'm trying to do.*

[image: Image 1 (boolean modifier no effect)] [image: Image 2 (boolean modifier removed everything except the text)][image: real life prototype]

Circle Curve Properties:
Location:
X: 0
Y: 0
Z: 0
Scale:
X: 1.5
Y: 1.5
Z: 2.0

Column Properties:
Location:
X: 0
Y: 0
Z: 0
Scale:
X: 1.5
Y: 1.5
Z: 2.0
Solidify Modifier:
Thickness: 0.01

Text Properties:
Location:
X: 0
Y: 0
Z: 0
Transform Scale: 0.75
Solidify Modifier:
Thickness: 0.01
Curve Modifier:
Deform Axis: -X

1. Select the cylinder in the 3D viewport.
2. In the Properties panel on the right-hand side of the screen, click on the "Modifiers" tab.
3. Click the "Add Modifier" button and select "Solidify" from the list of modifiers.
4. To cut text out of the side, first add a text object to the scene by selecting "Text" from the "Add" menu in the 3D viewport.
5. Type the desired text into the text object, and adjust the font and size in the "Object Data" tab of the Properties panel.
6. Add a curve object to the scene by going to Add -> Curve -> Circle
7. Scale and position the circle object so that it has the same diameter and position as your cylinder object.
8. Select the text object, then go to the "Modifiers" tab in the Properties panel (the wrench icon).
9. Click "Add Modifier" and select "Curve" from the list of modifiers.
10. In the "Curve" modifier settings, select the circle object as the curve to use.
11. Adjust the "Deform Axis" setting to "X" or "Y" (whichever is perpendicular to the text direction) and the "Deform Method" to "Stretch".
12. Position the text object so that it intersects with the cylinder where you want the text cut-out to be.
13. With the text object selected, go to the "Object" menu at the top of the screen and select "Convert to Mesh". This will turn the text object into a mesh object that can be used for Boolean operations.
14. Select the cylinder object, then go to the "Modifiers" tab in the Properties panel and add a "Boolean" modifier.
15. In the Boolean modifier settings, set the "Operation" to "Difference" and the "Object" to the mesh object created from the text object.
16. Apply the Boolean modifier, and the text should now be cut out of the side of the cylinder.

Comment: Hello and welcome, you should extrude your text more and see if that help, from the image, it does not look like it's deep enough

Comment: please provide blend file so we can check out it on our own. thx